# Printer Redirection RDS Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, printing, remote-desktop-services

I have a 2012 R2 RDS environment with a Farm containing two RDS servers, RDS Broker and RDS Gateway. Previously, I had printer redirection disabled, but I'm bringing on some users that need this functionality. I tried managing the functionality with CAPs. I configured two Gateway Connection Authorization Policies (CAP). One is disabling and the other is enabling. This has not been helpful.

I know that printer redirection is a Computer policy and it can't be filtered based on User, but I've found where the setting can be managed (disabled/enabled) on the user account within the Environment tab, but that hasn't been working either. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the right combinations of GPOs and settings.

I don't know what should be disabled or enabled. I don't know where the Group Policies should be configured or what settings to configure. I've spent almost a week researching this and my users are beginning to get frustrated and so am I.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I setup two CAP policies for disabling printer redirection and enabling printer redirection. I then configured user groups for each. Once I assigned the users to the respective groups, I configured a Computer GPO only to enable printer redirection, added the two RDS servers in the scope of the policy and linked the policy to the OU where the RDS servers live. Once I did that, I could change group membership and depending on the group, the printers would either redirection or not.